# Is there a way to install the ios-universal-framework on a cloudbees spawned Jenkins slave?

Tags: ios, jenkins, sudo, cloudbees, ios-universal-framework

Using a Master Jenkins on premises, and the cloudbees plugin, I am able to kick off iOS builds to a cloud bees instance. It's pretty sweet.

My IOS developers require cloning the ios-universal-framework repo, and then running an install.sh script contained within that repo. Everything works fine until the script issues a "sudo" command to copy files into the directory

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications"

The cp command needs sudo privileges. I'm thinking this is not possible but since I'm on the free trial plan, this is where I can find support. Thanks to all for reading.

Tony